# CSS Grid with Angular | Don't distribute grid items equally on width

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a app which has rows and columns. I can dynamically remove rows. When I remove them then the other items distribute themself equaly over the width of the grid.

Now I want to have something like flex, but with grid. The grid items should have a margin to the next item beside them. [Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE9qZ.png). And not distribute themself over the width.

**CSS**

```
.column {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px 0;
      display: grid;
      grid-auto-flow: column;
      .row-item {
        text-align: center;
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-rows: 25px;
        grid-row-gap: 10px;
        width: 9vw;
      }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="column">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let jS of journeyStepDisplay">
    <div *ngIf="jS.display" class="row-item">
      <div class="column-item header">
        <p>{{ jS.name }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a minimum and/or a max width of the grid items that are to be distributed, you can use a combination of different grid properties to get the desired outcome, like

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 100px));`

In the example below, we have a grid where the items will be distributed evenly with a min/max width of 100px. If they can't fit into the row a new row will be inserted.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  gap: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 100px));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare width for each item.

```
<div class="column">
  
    <div class="row-item">
      <div class="column-item header">
        <p>ciao</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="row-item">
      <div class="column-item header">
        <p>ciao2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="row-item">
      <div class="column-item header">
        <p>ciao3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

```
.column {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.row-item {
        text-align: center;
}
```

[here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) a useful guide.
(I didn't use directive from angular, but you can add it)